# How to efficiently get maximum value and its origin in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

does anyone know a more efficient, and dynamic, way of assigning the maximum value and its origin to columns in a data.table. An mtcars example is shown below

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
set(DT, j = 'maxColName', value = DT[, names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)], .SDcols = c('gear', 'carb')])
```

The column maxColName contains the column *name* of the highest value (where just gear and carb are taken into consideration). I need both the value and it's origin, so I figured that it's faster to save the origin and use that with `get()` or something similar instead of calculating the maximum twice.

In this scenario there are only two columns, so you can easily extract the maximum value but I believe that there's a better way to do it than this:

```
DT[maxColName == 'gear', 'maxValue' := gear]
DT[maxColName == 'carb', 'maxValue' := carb]
```

I've fiddled around with the `get()` function but no dice so far. The result I'd like would be this:
[image]
Where the new columns contain the name and the maximum value of all the columns that were considered

Comment: Why are you worrying about efficiency here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to get the maximum is:

```
cols <- c('gear', 'carb')
DT[, maxValue := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = cols]
```

Then if there are only two columns you could use a simple `fifelse()`:

```
DT[, maxColName := fifelse(gear == maxValue, "gear", "carb")]
```

This logic *could* be extended to more columns (but the original solution is probably better):

```
DT[, maxColName := fcoalesce(Map(\(nm, x) fifelse(x == maxValue, nm, NA), cols, .SD)), 
   .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: I couldn't get pmax to work with a dynamic vector of columns but do.call works indeed. Thank you! Any idea how this would change for 3 or more columns? pmax is no problem but extracting the name becomes trickier..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right about using `get()`, which I would just put in a `for` loop:

```r
sd_cols <- c("gear", "carb")
for (col in sd_cols) {
    DT[maxColName == col, maxValue := get(col)]
}

#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb maxColName maxValue
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>     <char>    <num>
#  1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4       carb        4
#  2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4       carb        4
# ---                                                                                      
# 31:  15.0     8   301   335  3.54 3.570 14.60     0     1     5     8       carb        8
# 32:  21.4     4   121   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2       gear        4
```

A word of warning is considering what happens when you have ties. The second row of `mtcars` has a max of `4` for both `gear` and `carb`. My version of `data.table` using R `4.2.2` on Ubuntu has produced `2` as the output of `max.col(.SD)`. The result is the value in `maxColName` is `carb`, i.e. `names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)]`. Your setup seems to have produced `1` for `max.col(.SD)`, as the screenshot shows `gear`. If there can be ties in any row of your your real data you will need to make sure you know how they're being dealt with.

Comment: Thank you! Yes handling ties can be given as a parameter to max.col (defaults to random) and I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @TrainedMusician thanks - I had no idea that ties defaulted to random.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation, where the target columns are melted long, and `first()` is used to capture the result

```
DT[melt(DT[,i:=.I][,.SD, .SDcols = c("i", cols)], "i")[order(-value), first(.SD),i], on="i"]
```

Output:

```
      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     i variable value
    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <int>   <fctr> <num>
 1:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4     1     gear     4
 2:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4     2     gear     4
 3:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1     3     gear     4
 4:  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1     4     gear     3
 5:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2     5     gear     3
 6:  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1     6     gear     3
 7:  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4     7     carb     4
 8:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2     8     gear     4
 9:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2     9     gear     4
10:  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0     4     4    10     gear     4
11:  17.8     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.90     1     0     4     4    11     gear     4
12:  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3    12     gear     3
13:  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3    13     gear     3
14:  15.2     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.780 18.00     0     0     3     3    14     gear     3
15:  10.4     8 472.0   205  2.93 5.250 17.98     0     0     3     4    15     carb     4
16:  10.4     8 460.0   215  3.00 5.424 17.82     0     0     3     4    16     carb     4
17:  14.7     8 440.0   230  3.23 5.345 17.42     0     0     3     4    17     carb     4
18:  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1    18     gear     4
19:  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2    19     gear     4
20:  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1    20     gear     4
21:  21.5     4 120.1    97  3.70 2.465 20.01     1     0     3     1    21     gear     3
22:  15.5     8 318.0   150  2.76 3.520 16.87     0     0     3     2    22     gear     3
23:  15.2     8 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2    23     gear     3
24:  13.3     8 350.0   245  3.73 3.840 15.41     0     0     3     4    24     carb     4
25:  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2    25     gear     3
26:  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1    26     gear     4
27:  26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2    27     gear     5
28:  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2    28     gear     5
29:  15.8     8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4    29     gear     5
30:  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6    30     carb     6
31:  15.0     8 301.0   335  3.54 3.570 14.60     0     1     5     8    31     carb     8
32:  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2    32     gear     4
      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     i variable value
```